# Stored Procedure Parameter working incorrectly

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, procedure

I am running an SQL stored procedure with phpMyAdmin. I am using a Netflix 2023 database and running the following procedure.

```
SELECT Title,Genre,HoursViewed
FROM Netflix2023
WHERE Genre LIKE '%'+@MainGenre+'%'
ORDER BY HoursViewed DESC;
```

This does not output anything when I set MainGenre to be Drama.

However, when I run the following query

```
SELECT Title,Genre,HoursViewed
FROM Netflix2023
WHERE Genre LIKE '%Drama%'
ORDER BY HoursViewed DESC;
```

I do get rows output correctly. Can someone help with my stored query?

Comment: The standard SQL string concatenation operator is `||`, not `+`. So, `+` is wrong. In MySQL, however, the `||` only works in certain modes (namely 'ANSI' or 'PIPES_AS_CONCAT'), For this reason it is common in MySQL to use the concatenation function `CONCAT` instead, which works regardsless from the mode you are working in.

Comment: MySQL should of course raise an error on the invalid operator. Instead, it converts all your strings into numbers in order to do the addition. And there is just the next weird behavior in MySQL; when your string is not numeric, it doesn't throw an error as should be expected, but just takes as many characters from the left that can represent a number, and if there are none, then it even returns a zero. So, MySQL turns `'%'+@MainGenre+'%'` into 0 + 0+ 0 = 0, which it then converts into the string '0' in order to apply the string function `LIKE`.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you should use the `CONCAT` function instead of the `+` for string concatenation

You should update the stored procedure to match the following example

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE GetMoviesByGenre(IN MainGenre VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT Title, Genre, HoursViewed
    FROM Netflix2023
    WHERE Genre LIKE CONCAT('%', MainGenre, '%')
    ORDER BY HoursViewed DESC;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I also saw that some versions of SQL had the @ symbol in front of parameter names. Phpmyadmin apparently does not use the @ symbol in front of parameter names.

Comment: @CJConti this has nothing to do with PHPmyAdmin, you just used the wrong MySQL syntax. Check the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.2/en/create-procedure.html